# WCF local only NamedPipe

Tags: wcf, named-pipes, self-hosting, usersession

Here's a simple example of my problem. I'm writing an application that self hosts a WCF service for communication only within the user's session. When multiple users run this application concurrently on a terminal services machine, all the users are happy as long as they don't have local admin rights. The problem begins if two or more users are admins, the 1st user creates the service, a 2nd user because the service has been created Globally...

Simple Win32 implementation, without WCF, would be create a named pipe with the "Local\" prefix. WCF appears to first attempt to create a global shared memory mapping, after that fails, then creates a local mapping.

Has anybody found a way to self host a WCF service that is local to the current user's session, even if the user is a local admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is just have each instance use a different service URL (deriving it from some characteristic of the user session to make it unique - e.g. session logon ID).

There's no way to stop the WCF binding publishing its endpoint details (aka the real pipe name) in the Global namespace if it's running with sufficient privileges to do so. But maybe you could adjust the process token privileges to disable the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege before opening the service host, if your service finds it is running as admin with elevated privileges.

Comment: Looks good, I just dont understand why microsoft wouldn't have made a way to specify scope when using the namedpipes...